# Remove Listbox item if match not found in VBA

Tags: vba

I am writing vba code that will search all listbox items against a entire column in a sheet.
If listbox item not found in Excel sheet column, i want to delete the item from list. I tried few codes, its showing some error as "Could not get list property, Invalid property array index". Below is my code i am using currently.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim itemExistResults As Boolean
    Dim myarray()
    Dim intItem As Long

    myarray = Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("a2:a1000"))

    For intItem = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If IsInArray(ListBox1.List(intItem), myarray) Then
        Else
            ListBox1.RemoveItem intItem
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1
End Function
```

Any idea where i am wrong in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate from the last item of list to the first, because removing items changes their indexation.

Try to change your loop like that:

```
    For intItem = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If IsInArray(ListBox1.List(intItem), myarray) Then
        Else
            ListBox1.RemoveItem intItem
        End If
    Next
```

---

I have a tip for you connected with your task, but not exactly with the error described in question.

For this type of task you should use object of `Dictionary` type instead of iterating through array - it would be much more effective.

I have modified your code to use dictionary. Check it and compare the time each of those solutions need to complete this task - the one with dictionary should be much faster. If you have any questions regarding this code, let me know in comments.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim intItem As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim value As Variant


    '--- [Loading data into dictionary] ------------------------------------
    Set dict = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    myArray = Sheet1.Range("A2:A1000")

    'Iterate through all the items in array and load them into dictionary.
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)

        value = myArray(i, 1)

        If Not IsEmpty(value) Then
            If Not dict.exists(value) Then
                Call dict.Add(value, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------



    '--- [Comparing ListBox with dictionary] -------------------------------
    With ListBox1
        For intItem = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            value = .List(intItem)

            If Not dict.exists(value) Then
                .RemoveItem intItem
            End If

        Next
    End With
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------

End Sub
```